# HC-05 Bluetooth module got virus

Tags: hc-05

We have a problem. Our HC-05 Bluetooth module got virus. We checked it in serial monitor and found out that the output is wrong. It has a mirrored question marks(⸮)and variables(b⸮, bW⸮, k⸮, U) which is not included in our codes. How can we fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely this module got a virus. It sounds more like a data rate mismatch or a noisy connection.

If you get ONLY the strange characters and nothing that you would expect, even in part, then confirm that the serial port speeds are equal on both the Arduino and the HC-05 module.

If you get some expected data, with junk characters mixed in, then check that your wires are secure and that you have connected all grounds from the Arduino and HC-05 module together with the power supply ground.

Answer (score 0):

Your module does NOT have a virus (Who would waste their time writing a virus for a bluetooth module...?!?!). You either have a bad baud rate setting, bad wiring, or you are trying to use a high baud rate coupled with SoftwareSerial.

Comment: Sorry because it's our first time to encounter this kind of problem so thank you guys for helping me out. Thank you very much!